# Comment traduire « rights holder » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, droit-et-justice

Le contexte était

> *More insidious are the restrictions on communication imposed on users by private network operators or intellectual property **rights holders**.*

J'ai essayé *titulaires de droits d'auteurs*, *propriétaires de droits d'auteurs*… mais rien ne marche vraiment. Des idées ?

Comment: [mouviciel](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4468/comment-traduire-rights-holder/4469#comment8144_4469) soulève la question intéressante de la portée géographique de ces droits : idéalement, tu traduis par un terme qui reflète aussi les véritables droits qu'ont leurs propriétaires là où sont tes lecteurs (i.e. si les *rights holders* sont étrangers, il faut se demander s'ils *holdent* vraiment quelque chose du point de vue de la judidiction française).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La première pensée qui m'est venue à l'esprit est *détenteur de droit*, et c'est exactement ce qu'utilise l'Organisation mondiale du commerce dans [ce texte](http://www.wto.org/french/docs_f/legal_f/27-trips_05_f.htm) sur le respect des droits de propriété intellectuelle.

Version anglaise (c'est moi qui souligne) :

> Members shall make available to **right holders** civil judicial procedures concerning the enforcement of any intellectual property right covered by this Agreement.

Version française :

> Les Membres donneront aux **détenteurs de droits** accès aux procédures judiciaires civiles destinées à faire respecter les droits de propriété intellectuelle couverts par le présent accord.

D'un autre côté, *détenteur de propriété intellectuelle* sous-entend que la personne détient les droits qui y sont attachés.

Terme connexe : [Ayant droit](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayant_droit); « personne détenant un droit du fait de son lien avec l'auteur ».

Article connexe utile : *[Titulaire, détenteur ou porteur?](http://canada.justice.gc.ca/fra/min-dept/pub/juril/no134.html)*, ministère de la Justice du Canada.

Comment: Pour moi, *ayant droits* est l'expression consacrée, mais peut-être est-ce plus journalistique que juridique.

Comment: D'après ce que j'ai pu comprendre, un *ayant droit* est généralement un membre de la famille de la personne qui détient le droit, non cette personne.

Comment: J'abonde pour _ayant droits_. Sachant qu'en France seuls les droits patrimoniaux (représentation, reproduction) peuvent être cédés à des tiers, les droits moraux (divulgation, intégrité) ne peuvent appartenir qu'à l'auteur.

Comment: @mouviciel : Aboundes-tu *pour* « ayant droits » — avec moi —, ou bien *concernant* « ayant droits », avec Kareen ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks - Avec toi, j'abonde _pour_ ayants droits. Mais je ne parle que de la France, pas des autres pays francophones dont le droit serait calqué sur d'autres systèmes.

Answer (score 3):

"*Ayant droit*" is the most convenient translation for right holders. Sometimes some English words need several words to be translated into French.

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que « *intellectual property rights* » forme au moins autant un bloc que « *right holders* », et je traduirais sûrement :

> … par les ayant droit de propriété intellectuelle…

Sauf si tu es prêt à faire une grosse périphrase, mais là tu n'as plus que l'embarras du choix.

Comment: C'est pour des sous-titres, donc la grosse périphrase on va éviter.